# ORA-06512: FN_CONVERT_ROWS_COLUMNS on select * from <TABLE_NAME>

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-06512

I am running into this error while running a simple sql queries on the table.

```
select * from <TABLE_NAME> 

select * from <TABLE_NAME> where rownum < 5 

select * from <TABLE_NAME> where rownum > 20 and rownum < 50
```

I am not familiar with the contents of the table but running the query so i know what is the content.

```
ORA-06512: FN_CONVERT_ROWS_COLUMNS
```

What should i do? the oracle help is not very helpful in this case.

Comment: "rownum > number" will never give you any rows.

Comment: @Notulysses corrected the question... i added a placeholder.. sorry about that..

Comment: The code you showed doesn't involve `FN_CONVERT_ROWS_COLUMNS`. You're just running plain queries in a client? Do you have anythnt else in the `where` clause?

Comment: @SarthakDudhara You do not provide enough information for anyone to help. I would recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Patrick issue is i have put as much information as I could from what I knew. I found from a colleague that it was a view that I was accessing and not a Table. The View definition had a statement that caused this error due to the data fetched for the view. So, we can safely close this question.